# Is it possible to access webpack config properties through the preview-head.html file for storybook.js?

Tags: ejs, storybook

I am trying to add storybook.js into my react project and there is a pre-requisite script I need to add to every storybook page so as to render some custom components.

The script's URL needs to be auto generated on the fly in webpack configuration.

This [Story rendering](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-rendering#adding-to-head) section of storybook's documentation mentioned a `preview-head.html` through which script tags can be injected into the final index HTML file.

I am wondering whether it supports EJS syntax like below for me to access a config option value of the HtmlWebpackPlugin.

```html
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.foobar %>"></script>
```

Comment: This an ongoing issue on storybook's github talking about [dyanmic preview-head.html](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11084) which is in idle state at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, I wrote a decorator in the `preview.js` file to purposely insert the `<script />` tag into the storybook iframe with dynamically generated `src` field.

```js
const loadAssets = () => {
  const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

  // scriptElement.src = /* dynamically generated from dependencies */; 

  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(scriptElement);
};
const AssetLoader = props => {
  React.useEffect(() => loadAssets(), []);
  return <>{props.children}</>;
};
const assetLoaderDecorator = storyFn => (
  <AssetLoader>{storyFn()}</AssetLoader>
);

addDecorator(assetLoaderDecorator);
```

It's a bit clumsy but it serves the purpose at the moment.

Inspired by https://github.com/jhta/storybook-external-links.